# Getting internal server error on deploying ML model to Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my model in google cloud.

Here is the pseudo code.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Upload_image():
    acne_string=[]
    trust_score=[]
    files = []
    files.append(request.files["image1"])
    files.append(request.files["image2"])
    for each_num in range(2):
        img_data=files[each_num].read()
        ass, ts, = AI_MODEL(img_data)
        acne_string.append(ass)
        trust_score.append(ts)


    return json.dumps({"score": trust_score, "text": acne_string}, indent=4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', threaded=True, debug=True, port=5001)
```

I have created `main.py` and the above code rests in that, also, `requirements.txt`(contianing all the dependencies),`app.yaml`(python version).

I did `gcloud app deploy`

The url is live.

`https://dermpod.appspot.com/`

But when I use postman to sent pictures to the url.

I am getting

*500 internal server error, either the server is overloaded or their is an error in the application.*

In postman, I am sending in the body of the URL the images.

I tried debugging by setting to display a messaage on the website.

```
 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Upload_image():



    return "Heloo it is alive!!"
```

and it is working.

Only problem is I am not able to upload the images to the instance and get the return json.

Comment: Are you sure that before entering the `for` loop `files` contains 2 valid images that you can `.read()` for every request to `/`?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Yes, i tested in the local system and it works fine.